# How to solve get_cv_idxs not available in new version fastai?

Tags: python, pandas, fast-ai

I am facing this issue when creating a collaborative filter using fastai.

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
from fastai import * 

ratings = pd.read_csv(ratings_path)
movies = pd.read_csv(movies_path, engine='python')
val_idxs = get_cv_idxs(len(ratings))
```

And I am getting this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-14332e30e55d> in <module>()
----> 1 val_idxs = get_cv_idxs(len(ratings)) #get validation indices
      2 wd=2e-4 #weight decay
      3 n_factors = 50 #dimension of embedding vector

NameError: name 'get_cv_idxs' is not defined
```

It seems like this function is only available in the older version fastai.
https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/old/fastai/dataset.py

Someone actually asked this question in fastai's forum but yet to be answered.
https://forums.fast.ai/t/get-cv-idxs-missing-in-fastai-v1/51020

Does anyone know the solution? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
def get_cv_idxs(n, cv_idx=0, val_pct=0.2, seed=42):
  np.random.seed(seed)
  n_val = int(val_pct*n)
  idx_start = cv_idx*n_val
  idxs = np.random.permutation(n)
  return idxs[idx_start:idx_start+n_val]
```